# How to store Datetime to a variable in VBA to save in Excel database

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have this Datetime stamp that I got from a textbox(Named: DateTime), which I want to save in my Excel database.

[image: DateTime Stamp on Textbox]

I have researched online and on this website to no avail. One of the answers here says that I need to parse the DateTime first before saving it to a variable. So I followed the suggestion.

```
    Dim I1 As Variant
    Dim ConvertDate As Date

    I1 = Split(DateTime, Space(1))
    ConvertDate = DateValue(I1(4) & Space(1) & I1(1) & ", " & I1(2)) + TimeValue(I1(3))
```

I used the code above but it is making a Subscript out of Range error. When I hover in each I1, the I1(4) is saying  "I1(4)=. It is not reading the Month. I1(1) says the day, I1(2) the Year and the I1(3) the time.

Is this the best method in saving DateTime as a variable? What error did I make?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to do this. I propose this method:

```
Sub test()
  Dim sDate As String
  Dim dt As Date

  sDate = "February 18, 2020 20:53:11"

  If IsDate(sDate) Then

    ' convert this format (mmmm d, yyyy hh:mm:ss) into an actual date variable
    dt = CDate(sDate)

    ' display it for debug purposes
    MsgBox dt

    ' store it into access (not part of your question despite your title)

  Else
    MsgBox sDate & " is not a valid date.", vbCritical
  End If

End Sub
```

It will work in your specific case at least.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried your proposed method. Unfortunately, when I save it to my excel database it saved only the date, not with the time.

Comment: What code did you use to save it? You did not include that in your question.

Comment: Since there is no "other way" to include the time in your Excel spreadsheet, I can only guess that your spreadsheet is formatting the date/time to show only the date.